# Windows host process won't stop duplicating itself

Tags: windows-10, malware

This just happened a few hours ago. Whenever I use the PC it's always the System process using lots of CPU usage, and I see that there are a LOT of windows dll processes.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/0e7cb304ac9789dd4aa7d53187540039.gif]

As soon as I exit my antivirus, the dlls are unleashed and my entire taskmanager is full of the DLL processes. They won't stop duplicating themselves.

To the point that I can't do anything and the computer slows to a crawl and stops doing anything, so I just force shut down by hitting the reset button (the one below the power button on my tower).

What is the cause of this? Just ran malwarebytes and my antivirus and they both came up fine.

I rightclicked the processes and they're from c:/windows/system32 so i think they're fine.

edit: seems they're related to nvidia container? (process explorer)

[image]

another edit:

i did an actual normal restart by clicking shutdown in the startmenu then starting it up normally.

it was at 100% for a minute or two upon startup (normal for me) then died down.

seems to have been fixed on my end

Comment: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/identify-loaded-rundll32exe-in-windows-task-list/  ... BTW, `tasklist /m /fi "IMAGENAME eq nvcontainer.exe"` will work for nvcontainer.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [Clean Boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) to find out the culprit:

To place the computer in a clean boot state. If the issue doesn’t appear, you can determine which one can be the cause by using dichotomy in MSconfig. Checking on half of Non-Microsoft service and restart, determining which half of the services cause the issue and repeating to check half of the problematic half services.